# Dynamic checkbox component in Lightning, unable to get event in controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events

I am creating dynamic checkbox component in Lightning in helper class but I am not able to capture click event in controller class as value is undefined for event.

**Helper**

```
 var checkBoxDef = [];
 var checkBoxCmps = [];

 checkBoxDef.push([

                "ui:inputCheckbox",

                    {
                       "class" : "design-checkbox",
                        "id" : "accordion-c-"+i,
                        "aura:id" : "accordion-c-"+i, 
                         "click": component.getReference("c.handlePress")
                    }

            ]);

 $A.createComponents(
        checkBoxDef,
        function(cmps, status, errorMessage){
            if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                for (var i = 0; i < cmps.length; i++) {
                    var checkBoxCmp = cmps[i];              
                    checkBoxCmps.push(checkBoxCmp);
                }
            }
            else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
                console.log("No response from server or client is offline.")
            }
            else if (status === "ERROR") {
                console.log("Error: " + errorMessage);
                }
            }
        );
```

**Controller**

```
handlePress : function(component) {
        var sectionId;
         console.log(component);

       if (event.target != undefined) {
           sectionId = event.target.id;
        } else {
            sectionId = event.getSource().getLocalId();
             }
         }
```

**Error**

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Action
>   failed: c:CCustomLightningPage$controller$handlePress [Cannot read
>   property 'target' of undefined] Failing descriptor:
>   {c:CCustomLightningPage$controller$handlePress}

Comment: I believe this has been a common problem with Locker service but I could also be missing something else that could be causing it. I know they were working on the event.target issue with the lightning namespace. Maybe @DougChasman could chime in

Comment: thanks for response .  event.target is working fine when I create the static checkbox instead of dynamic

Comment: @Jitendra I've answered this specific question below. If you've made the `event` parameter change and see a new issue, please open a new question with the full repro (.cmp, helper, controller file) and the new error or what things you have tried and what is not working as you'd expect.

Comment: Also, please only tag the question with "locker-service" if you think it's actually related to LockerService. From this question I don't see anything that would indicate that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the `event` parameter in your controller function. Change the following

`handlePress : function(component) { ... }`

to

`handlePress : function(component, event) { ... }`

Comment: thanks for response . but  changing handlePress : function(component) { ... }

to

handlePress : function(component, event) { ... }  method is not getting called

Comment: @Jitendra Trevor is right. Event is undefined in that method. If it is not getting called that is a separate issue